# Xcode Archive clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files

Tags: objective-c, xcode, clang, archive

I have a project that I can deploy to my iphone and simulator with no problem. When I try to archive it, I get a error.

Here is XCBuildConfiguration that was requested.

I don't know why i would randomly have this problem.  The only changes I have made recently was I added app icon images.

Comment: Could you post the XCBuildConfigutation section of your `.pbxproj` here please? (Everything between `/* Begin XCBuildConfiguration section */` and `/* End XCBuildConfiguration section */`)

Comment: Where can it be found?

Comment: Inside the `.xcodeproj` (which really just is a folder). Either use the terminal, or navigate to the xcodeproj in Finder, right-click on it and select "Show package content".

Comment: Try to clean project/derived data folder. This usually helps from random errors like this. Also you may try to create another project and add only JASidePanels pod there and try to reproduce error.

Comment: "generating multiple output files" is probably caused by the fact that clang can also compile header files to "precompiled header files".So will you please check all the import statement in the .pch file is between`#ifdef __OBJC__` and `#endif`.Are you using any .c file in your project ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Other C Flags build setting there is an `-iquote` argument that is not followed by the required directory argument. This causes the subsequent `-isystem` argument in the clang invocation to be interpreted as the directory for the stray `-iquote` and `/Users/ethan/WorkSpace/StudyTree/JASidePanels-master/../Pods/Headers` to be interpreted as an additional input file, resulting in the multiple output files error.

Either remove the `-iquote` argument from the build setting or add the directory argument.

Answer (score 0):

#### Try Setting `Enable Index-While-Building Functionality` to No.

In Xcode, `Build Settings` > `Build Options` > `Enable Index-While-Building Functionality` set it to "No".

If that worked, make sure to upvote this answer where I got it from:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48717558/293280